# Show the existence of two countable non-isomorphic models of DLO without endpoints under the assumption DLO is incomplete

Tags: solution-verification, model-theory

Homework question with a hint to use Löwenheim-Skolem and a hint to find a formula $\varphi$ which is true in one model and false in other model.

My (wrong) idea: Take $\mathbb{R}$ and interpret constants as $a^{\mathcal{M_1}}=a$ and $a^{\mathcal{M_2}}=-a$. Then $\mathcal{M_1}\models x>-x$ and $\mathcal{M_2}\not\models -x>x$. Then by Löwenheim-Skolem there exist two countable models of $\mathcal{M_1}$ and $\mathcal{M_2}$ and we're done. Not sure if it works this way though :(

Idea 2: Assume that DLO without endpoints is not complete. It follows that not all models of DLO are elementary equivalent, so there are at least two or none. Since both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are models of DLO, we know that it's the former. So let $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{M'}$ be models of DLO with $\mathcal{M}\not\equiv \mathcal{M'}$.

Since it is not elementary equivalent, $Th(\mathcal{M})\neq Th(\mathcal{M'})$ also holds and there is an $L$-statement $\varphi$ with $\mathcal{M}\models \varphi$ and $\mathcal{M'}\models \varphi$. Application of Löwenheim-Skolem downwards to these models of unknown cardinalities $\kappa, \kappa'$ shows existence of the countable models of DLO. Since $\mathcal{M}\models \text{DLO} \cup \{\varphi\}$ and $\mathcal{M}\models \text{DLO}$ they are not isomorphic.

Comment: Your solution has some typos (e.g. should be $\mathcal M’\models\lnot\varphi$), but the main argument is right. Also, if there were no models, then all models would be elementarily equivalent (vacuously), so that part is not correct, but like you say, there are models, so it doesn’t matter.

Comment: Actually one other detail: it’s important to note that all models of DLO are infinite, so you can use the downward LS theorem.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thank you! I prefer to write out my solution in painstaking detail so that I can catch my own mistakes in the process :)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen It's common to define "complete" to mean "complete and consistent" (i.e. for every sentence $\varphi$, $T\models\varphi$ or $T\models \lnot \varphi$, *but not both*). If that is the OP's definition, then observing that DLO is consistent is necessary in the proof.

Comment: @AlexKruckman True, but under either definition, "It follows that not all models of DLO are elementary equivalent, so there are at least two or none" is not quite accurate, if we're being pedantic. (Inaccurate in different ways, though.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ah, yes, good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many confusing things about your question. It seems something has gotten seriously scrambled between the statement of your homework question and your understanding of it.

1. The statement: "Show the existence of two countable non-isomorphic models of DLO without endpoints". This is impossible, because it directly contradicts Cantor's famous theorem that any two countable models of DLO (without endpoints) are isomorphic.
2. The hint: "find a formula $\varphi$ which is true in one mod and false in other model." This is again impossible because the theory DLO (without endpoints) is *complete*, so any two models satisfy exactly the same sentences.
3. Your attempt: "Interpret constants as $a^{\mathcal{M}_1} = a$ and $a^{\mathcal{M}_2} = -a$... Then $\mathcal{M}_1\models x>-x$ and $\mathcal{M}_2\not\models -x>x$." The language of the theory DLO (without endpoints) is $\{<\}$. This language has no constant symbols, and it does not contain the symbol $-$, so your models are not structures in the language of DLO, and your formulas are not formulas in the langauge of DLO. If you're considering a different language, that should be specified in the statement of the problem.

Also, to make $a > -a$ true in $\mathcal{M}_1$, you need to pick $a$ to be a *positive* real number. Having done this, with $a^{\mathcal{M}_2} = -a < 0$, we actually have $\mathcal{M}_2\models -a > a$, contrary to what you wrote. I think you mean to write $\mathcal{M}_2\not\models a > -a$.

---

Responding to the new solution: This is good, after spaceisdarkgreen's corrections in the comments.

1. You should observe that every model of $\mathsf{DLO}$ is infinite, so that you can apply Löwenheim-Skolem to $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{M}'$.
2. Typo: you should  have $\mathcal{M}'\models \lnot  \varphi$.
3. You finished with "Since $\mathcal{M}\models \text{DLO} \cup \{\varphi\}$ and $\mathcal{M}\models \text{DLO}$ they are not isomorphic." But this doesn't make any sense. You should say: If $\mathcal{N}\preceq \mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}'\preceq \mathcal{M}'$ are countable elementary substructures, then $\mathcal{N}\models \mathsf{DLO} \cup \{\varphi\}$ and $\mathcal{N}'\models \mathsf{DLO}\cup \{\lnot \varphi\}$, so they are not isomorphic.

Comment: Thanks very much. Now that I've reread the question, it says: We want to prove that DLO is complete. Assume it isn't complete and show under this assumption that two countable non-isomorphic models exist.

Comment: I'll update my question when I have a proof sketch.

Comment: Could you verify my new solution? Thanks!

Comment: @averagemathenjoyer I've edited